# How can I get a specific Lightning:inputField cmp without change the aura:id

Tags: lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield, aura-id

I have a component with 2 inputFields like this:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
 recordId="{!v.recordId}"
 aura:id="recordEditForm"
 objectApiName="Example__c"
>
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
  <lightning:inputField
   aura:id="inputField"
   value="{!item.From__c}"
   required="true"
   label="From"
   type="number"
   variant="label-stacked"
   onchange="{!c.onFromToChange}"
  />
  <lightning:inputField
   aura:id="inputField"
   value="{!item.To__c}"
   required="true"
   label="To"
   type="number"
   variant="label-stacked"
   onchange="{!c.onFromToChange}"
  />
 </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

And its controller:

```
  onFromToChange: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('onFromChange: ');
    var inputField = cmp.find("inputField");
    var fromField = ***want to get field From__c***;
    var toField = ***want to get field To__c***;
    if(fromField > toField) {
     //set customValidity for both fields
    }
  },
```

When I change the value of From__c or To__c field. I want to get the component of both these fields to set the customValidity for both fields. How can I achieve this issue **without separate the aura:id of them**? Please help

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm), if there are multiple components with same aura:id, it returns **array** of the components - so you need to iterate the array to set custom validity to each one - this way you can avoid individual ids.